# How to connect by user/password in JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code that connects to a broker by url. I do not understand how to make connections also by login / password?

```java
public static QueueSession getQueueSession(String urlBroker) throws JMSException {
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://" + urlBroker);
    QueueConnection connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    return connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
}
```

Comment: Not yet due to workload. I will give feedback tomorrow

Comment: Everything worked out! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html) (and its sub-classes like [`QueueConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueConnectionFactory.html) and [`TopicConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TopicConnectionFactory.html)) has methods to create a `Connection` or `JMSContext` using username & password, e.g.:

- [`createConnection(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [`createContext(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

In your case you could use something like:

```java
public static QueueSession getQueueSession(String urlBroker, String username, String password) throws JMSException {
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://" + urlBroker);
    QueueConnection connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection(username, password);
    return connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
}
```

It's worth noting that this method has a fairly serious **bug** because it is leaking a `QueueConnection` instance every time it's invoked. A connection like this is important to manage carefully. Please don't lose the reference to this instance so you can close it later when you're done with it. Otherwise you're going to waste resources on the broker potentially degrading performance and preventing other clients from connecting.